# Protractor not finding the same element after a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, protractor

I'm trying to obtain the text from a  element in protractor, and after doing something with the text, i want to click on the same  element. This is what i have

HTML:

```
<span class="span-user" id="spanuser"> {{user?.login}}</span>
```

Protractor test:

```
describe('Login OK with correct pass', () => {
    it('should login successfully with admin account', () => {
        // logging

        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys('admin');
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys('admin');
        element(by.css('button[type=submit]')).click();
        // check if the username <span> has the current login username

        const expect2 = /admin/;
        const spanuser = element(by.css('span#spanuser'));
        spanuser.getText().then((value) => {
            console.log('inside');
            console.log(value ? value : 'no value');
            expect(value).toMatch(expect2);
        });
        // then i try to click on the same span, to do some stuff

        spanuser.click().then(() =>  {
            console.log('It has been pressed!');
        });
    });
});
```

The first part works just fine, it gets the test and it passes the expect, but when i try to do the click() function on the span, i get the following error:

> Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 5 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for moredetails: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
>
> While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector,
>   span#spanuser)

What have i tried:

- browser.waitForAngular() before spanuser.click()
- browser.wait(10000) before spanuser.click()
- also i have a waitForAngular() in the beforeAll function.

Does anyone has a idea on this? It doesn't really make any sense to me, why wouldn't find the same element that has already found before?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` before spanuser.click()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `browser.waitForAngularEnabled('false')` in `onPrepare` of protractor conf.js

```
onPrepare: function() {
   browser.waitForAngularEnabled('false')
   // if you set this in onPrepare(), it will be a global setting, will
   // effect all script, so you no need to set it in other place.
}
```

Comment: Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: Added that line, now it doesn't even pass the first expect. ERROR: Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, span#spanuser)

Comment: Just in case, the element does exist, as it has been found before

Comment: Fixed, i just had to wait manually, with browser.sleep(10000)

Answer (score 0):

use the jasmin defaulttimeoutinterval in config instead of manual sleep

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 250000
    },
     allScriptsTimeout: 180000
```